# CSS conflicts with other CSS file in ck editor

Tags: html, css

Hiii,
I am using CK editor in my website. But, when implement that on my webpage then CSS file of CK editor is working fine but the CSS file made for page is not working and page is style less.

Here is my code that I implemented:-

```
<?php 
include '../path1.php';
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["username"]))
   header("location:$path/master/index.php");

$vendormaker=$_SESSION["username"];
include("connect.php");
?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Group Product</title>

<script src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/abc.css">
</script>

</head>

<body>

<div class="add_info">
   <div class="list-heading">
   <b>Group Product Content</b>
   </div>

<form action="" method="post">

<?php
include 'connect.php';
?>

<form>
  <table  cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="1" width="100%" >
  <tr style="color:White;background-color:#5D7B9D;font-weight:bold;">
    <th>Brand Name</th>
    <th>Category Name</th>
    <th>Sub Category Name</th>
    <th>Special Category Name</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
     <select name="brandname" id="brandname1">
     <option>Select The Brand</option>
     <?php
     $simage1="select * from brand";
     $a=mysql_query($simage1);
     while($row=mysql_fetch_array($a))
     {
     ?>
     <option value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" >
     <?php echo $row['name']; ?>
     </option>
     <?php }?>
     </select>
    </td>

    <td>
     <select name="categoryname" id="categoryname1">
     <option>Select The Category</option>
     <?php
     $simage1="select * from category";
     $a=mysql_query($simage1);
     while($row=mysql_fetch_array($a))
     {
     ?>
     <option value="<?php echo $row['category_id']; ?>" >
     <?php echo $row['category_name']; ?>
     </option>
     <?php }?>
     </select>
    </td>

    <td>
     <select name="subcategoryname" id="subcategoryname1">
     <option>Select The Subcategory</option>
     <?php
     $simage1="select * from subcategory";
     $a=mysql_query($simage1);
     while($row=mysql_fetch_array($a))
     {
     ?>
     <option value="<?php echo $row['subcategory_id']; ?>">
     <?php echo $row['subcategory_name']; ?>
     </option>
     <?php }?>
     </select>
    </td>

    <td>
     <select name="specialcategoryname" id="specialcategoryname1">
     <option>Select The Special Category</option>
     </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  </table>

 <div style="margin-top:20px"></div>
 <table>
 <tr>
  <td><label>Full Description:</label></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td width="80%">
  <textarea class="ckeditor"  id="content" name="content" style="width:500px;    
  height:300px;"></textarea>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions for this???

Comment: You aren't including a css for ckEditor, so you probably have something wrong in your link rel. Is it the correct path/name?

Comment: CSS for ckeditor is working fine, but "<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/abc.css">" is not working on my webpage and CK Editor is using its css file internally.

Comment: Yeah but you are not including a css for ckEditor, so that shouldn't be it (you can add multiple css files anyway). Or does your css work when you remove ckEditor?

Comment: Yes, when i remove ckEditor then my css for webpage works fine.

Answer (score 1):

How could I not see that lmao. Your stylesheet is in the `<script>` tags. Place it in your head outside of the script tags.

Comment: I just created my own page with ckEditor and a stylesheet. It has no problems at all, just re-check all your code, and make sure everything is complete (you're missing type="text/css" in your link rel).

Comment: Thanks sir for your help. The code is working fine now.There was problem in the CSS file that i was using for the webpage. Now, i changed whole of coding in css file and now it is working fine.

Comment: Great! Good luck with your project.